# Can we construct a complete classification of the ways that the shareholders' equity of a company can change?

Tags: equities, accounting

One of the most straightforward approaches to investing involves predicting how the book value, or shareholders' equity, of a company will change over time.  This in turn requires that we know the various way that this value *can* change.

For example, here is one tentative high-level classification of the various ways that book value may change over a given financial reporting period:

1. The company may post a positive or negative net income.
2. The company may issue a dividend to shareholders.
3. The company may sell or buy back its own stock.
4. The company may convert "commitments and contingencies" with a liquidation preference higher than common stock (say, a class of preferred stock) into common stock.

Are there other possibilities besides the above four?  Should this classification be modified in other ways?

(I apologize if this question seems basic, but I have studied it on and off over the past several days and don't yet have a satisfactory answer.)

Comment: The listed items fully descibe firm specific or economic reasons the book value of equity can change. Other reasons which are not firm-specific could be geopolitical risks (e.g. war), expropriation, fraudulent management, legal actions, natural disasters,…

Comment: @skoestlmeier How would those affect equity outside of the given 4 classifications? Seems like they would all affect net income which is what, in turn, affects equity.

Comment: For corp. misconduct, a fraudulent general statement has to be restated. My other examples refer to the uncertainty of the financial loss. You are not allowed to report a position in the income statement which is not quantifiable (accruals e.g. are based on events that are probable, so more likely than 50%). But they do affect the equity for shareholders, even we may not quantify the change in US-$.

Comment: I'm still processing skoestlmeier's interesting comments, but wanted to clarify that (as D Stanley's comment suggests) I am primarily interested in what U.S.-style GAAP accounting would suggest is the most natural high-level way to classify the possible changes to book value.  For simplicity, let's assume that all financial statements are accurately prepared (e.g., without fraud).